# How to simulate return in emacs minibuffer

Tags: emacs, elisp, minibuffer

What I want to do is, when I find myself using a function that prompts me for a value, and this value is ALWAYS the right one, to be able to bind the function to a key and auto-accept the answer, simulating a RET in the minibuffer.

Take for instance "[ido-switch-buffer](http://www.cua.dk/ido.el)". When entered, it prompts you for a buffer name, and proposes the last visited one.

(It can do a lot more, that's why I dont want to re-define it, I just want a wrapper around it)

Say I want to switch between the last visited two buffers, how would I say that in my .emacs ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You may bind any keyboard macro, which is essentially a sequence of keys, to a key.  For example,

```
(global-set-key (kbd "C-c b") (kbd "C-x b <return>"))
```

Comment: Mm.. Nope, not in this very case.

`(global-set-key  (kbd "C-<tab>") 'ido-switch-buffer)
(global-set-key  (kbd "C-<tab>") (kbd "C-<tab> <return>"))`

Only gives me `After 0 kbd macro iterations: Variable binding depth exceeds max-specpdl-size`

Comment: And I'd really like to know how, in elisp parlance, you say "accept what the minibuffer proposes"

Comment: The defined key should not be part of the defining sequence, which as you see will result in infinite recursion.

Answer (score 6):

You can do this with:

```
(switch-to-buffer (other-buffer))
```

Comment: That did the trick. Not the way I wanted, but the cat is skinned :) Thanks Michael !

Comment: @PhilippeCM Why did you accept this answer if it doesn't address your question in a general way like you wanted?  huaiyuan actually gave you exactly what you wanted, you just mis-applied the solution as an infinite loop.